# What is the use case of boost::hana forward declaration headers?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, forward-declaration, boost-hana

Most of the hana headers include also forward declaration headers contained in the subfolder `fwd`, e.g. `#include<boost/hana/fwd/pair.hpp`.

AFAIK forward declaration headers declare things instead of defining them, so the user can have a access limited to *pointers* (and references) to the functions and objects.

What sense does it make for `boost::hana`, which is header-only templated library? The only thing that comes to my mind is that forward declarations are good enough if you do not intend to instantiate the declared templates, but then - what is the point of using them in the first place?

By looking at the library source I sense it is something very smart, which I still do not comprehend.

---

Imagine I need only very specific instances of the `boost::hana` templates. Would it work, if I define *and instantiate* them in one translation unit, and link to them from all the other units, using forward declarations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little information on this in the manual [here](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-header_organization):

> This subdirectory contains the forward declaration of everything in
>   the
>       library. It is essentially a mirror of the `boost/hana/` directory, except
>       all the headers contain only forward declarations and documentation. For
>       example, to include the `hana::tuple` container, one can use the
>       `boost/hana/tuple.hpp` header. However, if one only wants the
>       forward declaration of that container, the `boost/hana/fwd/tuple.hpp`
>       header can be used instead. Note that forward declarations for headers
>       in `boost/hana/ext/` and `boost/hana/functional/` are not provided.

Also from a discussion with the author [here](https://gitter.im/boostorg/hana/archives/2015/12/10):

> The rationale is so that we can #include lightweight declarations
>   instead of full blown definitions when only a declaration is requried.
>   This can help with compile times. Also, it’s necessary for some
>   circularly-dependent stuff.

and:

> And finally, I think it makes for a nice separation between interface
>   and implementation, and also it gives a place to systematically put
>   documentation. Since the implementation is sometimes hairy, I think
>   it’s nice not to entangle the documentation with it.

There it is straight from the horse's mouth. I've found it is quite necessary to separate implementation for the whole chicken/egg problem with circular dependencies. This is a clean way of doing that, that I've adopted in my own projects.

Comment: While obviously forward declarations (and by extension, fwd headers) are needed with circular dependencies. However, I think it's fair to say that it is hardly a good default practice (because circular dependencies are usually a design smell; libraries like Hana are a highly specific subgenre, and therefore maybe an exception). +1 for the answer by the way